# StackOverflow RSS Feed only returns 30 Items

Tags: rss, syndication-feed

I use this code to get RSS from stackoverflow.com

```
SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(XmlReader.Create("http://stackoverflow.com/feeds"));
        foreach (SyndicationItem item in feed.Items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Title.Text);
            Console.WriteLine(item.Title.Type);
            Console.WriteLine(feed.Items.Count());
            Debug.Print(item.Title.Text);

        }
```

I get just 30 items but when I check in Google Reader I get more than this count.

Is there a limitation here?

Comment: Yes sorry i am many Tired ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

30 is what stackoverflow returns, it is not a limitation of the SyndicationFeed class.

Comment: it does not get more, it just remembers the older ones.

Comment: no no you can try and add new feed in your reader and then see that when scrolling get more than 30

Comment: New to you, maybe. But Google Reader is archiving many RSS feeds.

Answer (score 2):

Google Reader stores old articles from RSS feeds. So we are limited to what the RSS feed contains, but Google has an archive that'll let you keep scrolling.